# Open CV ROI extraction from animated tiff/gif

Tags: python, opencv, animation, tiff, extract

I am analysing a greyscale recording of synapses, from which I would like to automatically extract regions of interests (ROIs) as sets of small 'cuts' of the whole animation in order to be able to both trace and account for the movement of the microscope and to profile the Z-axis profile of a particular ROI. This means that I need to scan through the image, identify ROIs and match them 'over the frames', exporting the result as set of frames. Common ROI catching techniques (filtering, averaging over frames via Markov or Fourier and then matching the points) render images which are too blurred/skewed to be used for further analysis and they can't handle the amounts of motion happening in the image, and so I'm trying to come up with a different ROI tracing and extracting mechanism. Any ideas?

To illustrate:
Video (originally huge tiff file, compressed to gif for upload): [image: original recording]

Something along the lines of result 
[image: Desired result]

(this is a cut made in ImageJ, preferably my program would be able to either track my ROI or just cut out enough space to extract most of the on-screen appearance of ROI, but I'm not sure what else can be done)

Comment: I think the following might work. Register each frame to its successor via phase correlation. On each frame segment synapses (you can try thresholding/adaptive thresholding or maybe mean shift clustering method). Get the centers of thresholded objects and find correspondences from one frame to another with euclidean distance as a measure. Some heuristics will be needed to take care of new objects that come to FOV during the video. Same with objects that disappear.